# Div with background colour and border spacing

Tags: html, css

I am facing a strange issue with the `borders` and `background color`. If I apply `border` to the `div left` then it leaves some space at the far right. So the `background color` doesn't extend 100% for the first tab which is active.

```css
.col-3 {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 26.1%;
}
.tabs .col-3 {
  border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.col-3.active {
  background: #505050;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1280px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.full-width {
  background: #dfdedb none repeat scroll 0 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.main-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width container tabs">
  <div class="main-container active">
    <div data-id="tab-1" class="col-3 first text-center padding-top-bottom-small active">
      <h3 class="lato-reg mediumfontx4 orange">How to Sell <span class="deep-grey padding-left-tiny plus">+</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div data-id="tab-2" class="col-3 second text-center padding-top-bottom-small">
      <h3 class="lato-reg mediumfontx4 orange">Finance <span class="deep-grey padding-left-tiny plus">+</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div data-id="tab-3" class="col-3 text-center padding-top-bottom-small">
      <h3 class="lato-reg mediumfontx4 orange">Market Intelligence <span class="deep-grey padding-left-tiny plus">+</span></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What wrong am I doing. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gap still exists without the border, you just aren't seeing it because everything is the same gray color.

The reason the space exists is because the elements are inline and are sensitive to white space. You can either float them left or remove the white space:

```css
.col-3 {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 26.1%;
}
.tabs .col-3 {
  border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.col-3.active {
  background: #505050;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1280px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.full-width {
  background: #dfdedb none repeat scroll 0 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.main-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width container tabs">
  <div class="main-container active">
    <div data-id="tab-1" class="col-3 first text-center padding-top-bottom-small active">
      <h3 class="lato-reg mediumfontx4 orange">How to Sell <span class="deep-grey padding-left-tiny plus">+</span></h3>
    </div><!--
    --><div data-id="tab-2" class="col-3 second text-center padding-top-bottom-small">
      <h3 class="lato-reg mediumfontx4 orange">Finance <span class="deep-grey padding-left-tiny plus">+</span></h3>
    </div><!--
    --><div data-id="tab-3" class="col-3 text-center padding-top-bottom-small">
      <h3 class="lato-reg mediumfontx4 orange">Market Intelligence <span class="deep-grey padding-left-tiny plus">+</span></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Floated:

```css
.col-3 {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 26.1%;
  float:left;
}
.tabs .col-3 {
  border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.col-3.active {
  background: #505050;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1280px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.full-width {
  background: #dfdedb none repeat scroll 0 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.main-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width container tabs">
  <div class="main-container active">
    <div data-id="tab-1" class="col-3 first text-center padding-top-bottom-small active">
      <h3 class="lato-reg mediumfontx4 orange">How to Sell <span class="deep-grey padding-left-tiny plus">+</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div data-id="tab-2" class="col-3 second text-center padding-top-bottom-small">
      <h3 class="lato-reg mediumfontx4 orange">Finance <span class="deep-grey padding-left-tiny plus">+</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div data-id="tab-3" class="col-3 text-center padding-top-bottom-small">
      <h3 class="lato-reg mediumfontx4 orange">Market Intelligence <span class="deep-grey padding-left-tiny plus">+</span></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Space removed between divs:

```css
.col-3 {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 26.1%;
}
.tabs .col-3 {
  border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.col-3.active {
  background: #505050;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1280px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.full-width {
  background: #dfdedb none repeat scroll 0 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.main-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width container tabs">
  <div class="main-container active">
    <div data-id="tab-1" class="col-3 first text-center padding-top-bottom-small active">
      <h3 class="lato-reg mediumfontx4 orange">How to Sell <span class="deep-grey padding-left-tiny plus">+</span></h3>
    </div><div data-id="tab-2" class="col-3 second text-center padding-top-bottom-small">
      <h3 class="lato-reg mediumfontx4 orange">Finance <span class="deep-grey padding-left-tiny plus">+</span></h3>
    </div><div data-id="tab-3" class="col-3 text-center padding-top-bottom-small">
      <h3 class="lato-reg mediumfontx4 orange">Market Intelligence <span class="deep-grey padding-left-tiny plus">+</span></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for showing a method which doesn't use float left. Actually I am not too much sure about using float: left. Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.col-3` tabs are set to `display: inline-block;`.

Siblings with such display rule will always generate a space between one another.

There are multiple ways to fight this, you can try a `float: left;` on `.tabs .col-3`.

**Check this famous article from CSS-TRICKS for multiple ways to fight off the inline-block whitespace:**

https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `display:inline-block;`. It caused some extra space [which can be removed](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/). Alternatively, you can use `float:left;` instead of `display:inline-block;`. You don't need to assign `display:inline-block` to .col-3 if you use bootstrap.

```css
.col-3 {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 26.1%;
}
.tabs .col-3 {
  border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.col-3.active {
  background: #505050;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1280px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.full-width {
  background: #dfdedb none repeat scroll 0 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.main-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width container tabs">
  <div class="main-container active">
    <div data-id="tab-1" class="col-3 first text-center padding-top-bottom-small active">
      <h3 class="lato-reg mediumfontx4 orange">How to Sell <span class="deep-grey padding-left-tiny plus">+</span></h3>
    </div><!--
    --><div data-id="tab-2" class="col-3 second text-center padding-top-bottom-small">
      <h3 class="lato-reg mediumfontx4 orange">Finance <span class="deep-grey padding-left-tiny plus">+</span></h3>
    </div><!--
    --><div data-id="tab-3" class="col-3 text-center padding-top-bottom-small">
      <h3 class="lato-reg mediumfontx4 orange">Market Intelligence <span class="deep-grey padding-left-tiny plus">+</span></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `float:left` to `.col-3`
Here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lxa7ng5/)